# auth views not rendering templates in django

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication, django-urls

this is my entire urls.py file where I have designed custom templates for reset password functionality

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^articles/', include('article.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',{'template_name': 'reset_password.html'}),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done',{'template_name': 'password_reset_done.html'}),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',{'template_name': 'password_confirm.html'}),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',{'template_name': 'password_reset_complete.html'}),

    # 
    url(r'^', include('article.urls')),


    # user auth urls
    url(r'^home/$', 'defcon.views.home'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'defcon.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'defcon.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'defcon.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'defcon.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'defcon.views.invalid_login'),
    # user registration urls
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'defcon.views.register_user'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'defcon.views.register_success'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_auth/$', 'defcon.views.register_auth'),

    #Serve Media Files
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
]
```

I looked at the django documentation @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/ and from there I tried to add custom templates like this

```
url(
        '^password_reset/',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
        {'template_name': 'change-password.html'}
    )
```

I'm getting deafult django UI but I have custom template for this which is not showing up

```
{% extends "user_forms.html" %}

{% block main %}
<span class="fa fa-user bigicon"></span>
<h2>Enter Details</h2>
<form action = "" method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
<small>{{form.email.errors}}</small>

    <p>{{form.email}}</p>



<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" />Reset my password</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        document.getElementById("id_email").placeholder = "Enter Email";
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

in spite of adding the custom templates the templates are not getting rendered. the default django reset forms are visible.

Comment: More information required. How are you including this in your urls.py? What are the other URLs? What are the differences in the templates that you are not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the **django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset**  for the related view, but you should create a view in views.py in order to have a custom password reset form.

so in your views.py of the **app** create a class like

```
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    try:
        if request.POST:
            form = Change_password_form(request.POST)
            user = request.user.username
            old_password = request.POST['old_password']
            new_password1 = request.POST['new_password1']
            new_password2 = request.POST['new_password2']
            if form.is_valid():
            if new_password1 == new_password2 and old_password != new_password1:
                u = User.objects.get(username=user)
                u.set_password(new_password1)
                u.save()
                return render(request, '../templates/password_change_done.html')
            else:
                form = Change_password_form()
                return render(request, '../templates/password_change_form.html', {'form':form})
         else:
             form = Change_password_form()
             return render(request, '../templates/password_change_form.html', {'form':form})
    except:
           return render(request, '../templates/password_change_form.html', {'form':form})

class Change_password_form(forms.Form):
     old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Old Password'}), required=True)
     new_password1= forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password'}), required=True)
     new_password2= forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm New Password'}), required=True)
     action = forms.CharField(label="action", required=True)

     def clean(self):
         cleaned_data = super(Change_password_form, self).clean()
         old_password = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')
         new_password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
         new_password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
         action = self.cleaned_data.get('action')
         return self.cleaned_data
```

add the following url pattern in **urls.py**

> url(r'^/change-password/$', 'appname.views.change_password', name="change-password"),

Comment: I have done this for changing the password. But what i'm trying to implement is reset password functionality. If a user forgets its password then an email is sent to set new password. In your case the user knows his password and try to reset it to something else.